# Encrypt hook in mkinitcpio.conf for full system encryption USB drive Arch install

Tags: arch-linux, dependencies, hook, mkinitcpio

I have installed Arch Linux on a [USB drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Usb_install) with [full system encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_Entire_System#Simple_partition_layout_with_LUKS) using LUKS. The Arch wiki as usual walked me through almost everything. The only issue I ran into was using setting up the hooks in `mkinitcpio`. The Arch wiki says that for a USB install the `block` hook must come immediately after the `udev` hook. The wiki also says for encryption that the `encrypt` hook must come before, but not necessarily immediately, the `filesystem` hook. Following these rules I first tried:

```
HOOKS="encrypt base udev block autodetect modconf filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

but it didn't work, so I moved `encrypt` to be later:

```
HOOKS="base udev block autodetect modconf encrypt filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

and it works fine. This leads to my question. What are the dependencies for the `encrypt` hook and where can I find details about hook dependencies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your hooks are all here:

```
% ls /usr/lib/initcpio/{hooks,install}
/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks:
btrfs        dmraid   keymap  mdadm    mhwd-fb  miso_loop_mnt  net     shutdown  udev  v86d
consolefont  encrypt  lvm2    memdisk  miso     miso_pxe_nbd   resume  sleep     usr

/usr/lib/initcpio/install:
autodetect  consolefont  fw        mdadm_udev  miso_loop_mnt  pata    sd-encrypt   sleep    usbinput
base        dmraid       keyboard  memdisk     miso_pxe_nbd   pcmcia  sd-lvm2      strip    usr
bcache      encrypt      keymap    mhwd-fb     mmc            resume  sd-shutdown  systemd  v86d
block       filesystems  lvm2      miso        modconf        sata    sd-vconsole  udev     virtio
btrfs       fsck         mdadm     miso_kms    net            scsi    shutdown     usb
```

They're all shell scripts:

```
% cat /usr/lib/initcpio/{hooks,install}/encrypt
#!/usr/bin/ash
run_hook() {
    modprobe -a -q dm-crypt >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ "${quiet}" = "y" ] && CSQUIET=">/dev/null"
    # Get keyfile if specified
    ckeyfile="/crypto_keyfile.bin"
    if [ -n "$cryptkey" ]; then
        IFS=: read ckdev ckarg1 ckarg2 <<EOF
...
```

This is stuff you already know - it's very familiar.

Basically if you want something to happen in early userspace, you need only load the necessary kernel modules and act accordingly - that's all any of these hooks are doing.

If you want to know what's going on in the `initramfs` image, just take a peek:

```
% lsinitcpio --help lsinitcpio 17 usage: lsinitcpio [action] [options] 
usage: lsinitcpio [action] [options] <initramfs>

  Actions:
   -a, --analyze        analyze contents of image
   -c, --config         show configuration file image was built with
   -l, --list           list contents of the image (default)
   -x, --extract        extract image to disk

  Options:
   -h, --help           display this help
   -n, --nocolor        disable colorized output
   -V, --version        display version information
   -v, --verbose        more verbose output
```

`lsinitcpio` is handy, but it's nothing more than a helper shell function - just like the rest of those. When you look into your disk image you'll notice that it's really nothing more than that - just a regular linux root image after all:

```
% mkdir /tmp/init ; cd $_
% lsinitcpio $(printf /boot/*.img | head -n1) | grep -Eo '^./[^/]*' | sort -u
./VERSION
./bin
./buildconfig
./config
./dev
./etc
./init
./init_functions
./lib
./lib64
./new_root
./proc
./run
./sbin
./sys
./tmp
./usr
```

You can extract it:

```
% lsinitcpio --extract $(printf /boot/*.img | head -n1)
% ls
dev
etc
new_root
proc
run
sys
tmp
usr
VERSION
bin
buildconfig
config
init
init_functions
lib
lib64
sbin
```

And poke around:

```
% cat ./init_functions
...
default_mount_handler() {
    if [ ! -b "$root" ]; then
        err "Unable to find root device '$root'."
        echo "You are being dropped to a recovery shell"
        echo "    Type 'exit' to try and continue booting"
        launch_interactive_shell
        msg "Trying to continue (this will most likely fail) ..."
    fi
    msg ":: mounting '$root' on real root"
    if ! mount ${fstype:+-t $fstype} -o ${rwopt:-ro}${rootflags:+,$rootflags} "$root" "$1"; then
        echo "You are now being dropped into an emergency shell."
        launch_interactive_shell
        msg "Trying to continue (this will most likely fail) ..."
    fi
}
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue was that the hooks are executed in the order they are listed in the HOOKS line (which is just an array) in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`. Essentially, you were trying to run the encrypt script *before* the `base` hook, which provides the runtime necessities for booting<sup>1</sup>.

You can read about each of the hooks by issuing `mkinitcpio -H $hook`.

The [Arch Wiki mkinitcpio page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#HOOKS) has a good explanation. You can also read each of the hooks in `/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/` to see what is actually being run.

The `mkinitcpio` developer for Arch, Dave Reisner, also has a good post on [optimising mkinitcpio](http://blog.falconindy.com/articles/optmizing-bootup-with-mkinitcpio.html) which has a more detailed explanation of how it all fits together.

<sup>1. The Archwiki mkinitcpio page does make clear that you should always include the `base` hook first, "unless you know what you are doing." *Caveat lector*...</sup>